# No remote access to PostgreSQL db

Tags: postgresql, sql, remote-access

i'm stuck in connecting to a PostresSQL database from remote host.
The server is accepting incoming connections on port 5432 and i've configured pg_hba.conf like this:

```
local   all         all                          md5
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0        md5
```

and the postgresql.conf like this:

```
listen_addresses = '*' 
port = 5432
max_connections = 100
```

I don't have any problem accessing from local but when i try to connect via psql with something like this:

```
psql -U myuser -h hostname db_name
```

I get this error:

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "87.zz.yy.xxx", user "myuser", database "db_name", SSL off
```

I also tried to put the host 87.zz.yy.xxx in the pg_hba.conf file without success.